# Python возвращает пустую строку при чтении файла, а содержимое самого файла удаляет

Tags: python, файлы, txt

Открываю файлы в цикле из списка, почему-то сегодня что-то сломалось, и при открытии файла  возвращается пустая строка, а содержимое самого файла удаляется.

```
for i in range(len(channels_history_list)):
    with open(f"./output/{channels_history_list[i]}", "r", encoding="utf-16") as channel_history:
       text = channel_history.read().lower()
       print(text)
```

Лог:

> ```
> 18:31:46.44 >>> Call to zero_morph in File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\NLTK\main.py", line 55
> 18:31:46.44 .......... text = ''
>
> 18:31:46.44   55 |     def zero_morph(text):
> ```

Пример файла по [ссылке](https://anonfiles.com/I4Y6x5Mdy6/skabeeva_after_24.02.2022_txt)

**EDIT:**

```
channels_history_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./output/"):
    for name in files:
        if "frequency" not in name and name.endswith(".txt"):
            channels_history_list.append(name)
print(channels_history_list)
start_time = time.time()
    
print(os.getcwd())
for channel in channels_history_list:
    print(channel)
    # fname = r"C:\Users\Vadik\PycharmProjects\NLTK\output\" + channel

    with open(f"C:\\Users\\Vadik\\PycharmProjects\\NLTK\\output\\{channel}", "r", encoding="utf-16") as channel_history:
        text = channel_history.read().lower()
        print(text)
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Для меня **ваш код никакой проблемы не вызывает**, всё работает так, как вы хотели (с вашим примером файла), выводится полный текст файла со строчными буквами.

Значит, *ошибка не в программе,* а может быть

- **в неправильном пути** к вашим файлам (`./output/`), или
- **неправильном списке** этих файлов (`channels_history_list`).

Попробуйте заменить путь к файлам на *абсолютный* и проверите правильность списка файлов (например может быть, что он пустой).

Я создал такой список файлов:

```
channels_history_list = ["skabeeva_after_24.02.2022.txt", "skabeeva_after_24.02.2022.txt"]
```

(дважды тот же самый ваш файл, который я скопировал в правильную папку).

---

Между прочим, более питонский подход такой (разница *в первых двух строках*):

```
for channel in channels_history_list:
    with open(f"./output/{channel}", encoding="utf-16") as channel_history:
       text = channel_history.read().lower()
       print(text)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141294/discussion-on-answer-by-mariand-python------).